# geocoding cache refresh

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

Google recommends updating cached geocodes regularly but that is about it. What is the longest interval of time you would recommend (in general) to update a cached geocode? Weekly, monthly, quarterly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally cache for 1 month for country level, 1 week for [region level](https://gimmerank.com/en/KB/Config/Geotargeting#Region)

My reasons:

- GEO code will change "ONLY" when detection method changed or
  detection database changed. Not likely cause huge changes often, or
  ever
- Most people not travel lots